# Mongodb simple querying with sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query this model:

```
user = {
  'email': 'test@test.com',
  'pages': [
       {
          'name': 'best page',
          'sessions': [
              {
                 sessionName: 'abc',
              },

          ]
       }, ..
  ]
};
```

Basically I want to select 3 sessions data from one page sorted by `session._id` DESC.

```
User.findOne({ '_id': userId, 'pages._id': pageId })
    .select('pages.sessions')
    .sort({ 'pages.sessions._id': -1 })
    .limit(3)
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
    });
```

But nothing is working.. It's returning array of pages (instead of 1). Data are not sorted and there are all sessions instead of 3.

What should I change ?

**Edit:** found out that I can't sort it and I can limit it using `slice('pages.sessions')` but **how can I get only 1 page instead of array?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) :

```
Users.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "_id": "1",
        "pages._id": "1"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        email: 1,
        pages: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$pages',
                as: 'pages',
                cond: { $eq: ['$$pages._id', "1"] }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$pages"
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        email: 1,
        pages: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            sessions: {
                $slice: ["$pages.sessions", 3]
            }
        }
    }
}], function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
})
```

It first [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) your documents with required `_id`/`pages._id`, then [`filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) `pages` array depending on `pages._id`. Then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `pages` to be able to `slices` in the next [`project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

Comment: returning empty array, but I will take a look at aggregation. Thanks.

Comment: solved it using using mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId, pageId). Do you also know how to get only 1 result from my edited question (I guess using only that simple query + slice() is better for performance)?

Comment: What do you mean by 1 page/result ? Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: If I do User.findOne({'_id': userId, 'pages._id': pageId }) it returns array of pages (all pages that belongs to that user) not only page with _id: pageId

Comment: I've updated my post above with a new (simpler) aggregation but without $sort which gives the expected result

Comment: is it also possible to use $slice and select which items I want to return? Trying like so: sessions: { _id: 1, another: 1, $slice: [..] }

Comment: I've updated my post with more field in `$project`, you can also use `$$ROOT` for getting the root document in project stage

Comment: Yeah, it works on pages properties, but I ment sessions properties. I solved it using $project 2x (first selecting properties and then cutting it using slice)